# loading css style background-image url dynamically in c sharp

Tags: c#, css

Look this what i have

```
string imagePath = "http://" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DomainName") & "/images/"
htmlstring = <tr style='border-width: 0px; height: 36px; background-image: url(' " & imagePath & " cart_top_centbg.jpg');'>
```

here `imagePath` is set in web.config file but this is not geting loaded in that css style background-image, m i doin' something wrong here ?

Comment: I don't think that this is a css problem, as such. What language are you composing the `htmlstring` in?

Comment: @David Thomar: yeah this is not a css problem,but how to compose that backround image is the problem and its in C sharp

Comment: Thanks, @FosterZ, you might benefit from adding that to your tags for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code appears to be VB syntax? If you are in C#, you would need:

```
string imagePath = @"http://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DomainName"] + "/images/";

string htmlstring = "<tr style='border-width: 0px; height: 36px; background-image: url('" + imagePath + "cart_top_centbg.jpg');'>";
```